# How to stop pink/purple terminalpad window from opening when running console app in Visual Studio on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, terminal, console

At some point today, whenever I run the C# console app that I'm developing in Visual Studio 2022 on Mac, a pink/purple window opens with the title "TerminalPad-TerminalPad-0" in the frame of the window. An additional normal looking terminal window within which the application actually runs opens, takes keyboard input and displays output. When the application successfully completes, the pink/purple window goes away.

How do I stop this purple/pink window from opening?

I tried changing all the terminal options I could find in VS with no change. I don't know what I did to make this start happening.

Answer (score 1):

I started having this happen to me today (11/10/22) as well. There's another thread with the same issue, required a full uninstall with a 3rd party uninstaller ("App Cleaner and Uninstaller", has two day trial) and then full reinstall. Just dragging the Visual Studio icon to the trash won't fix it.

Comment: For reasons unknown to me, this annoying behavior stopped today without me making any more explicit attempts to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after a VS update.  I uninstalled using the Microsoft provided scripts linked to from within this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall?view=vsmac-2022

and currently leading to the script at this location (please double check above page if the below link is dead):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/master/mac/resources/uninstall-vsmac.sh

I then reinstalled using the MS provided installer for MacOS.  All working fine now.

It took around 15 mins in total to resolve.